Can’t import a token with phantom wallet on phone
I got an airdrop but I can’t add the new token. I can see it when I search it. But I can’t see my airdrop cause I can’t add the token. I added in the address book. But I still can’t see the airdrop?  Any help. Do I need to be on desktop?
